# Is it possible to move MacOS TMPDIR to another drive?

Tags: macos

Some programs write to the macOS TMPDIR that is on the booth volume, but unfortunately, some write huge files on it (for scratch disk, Lightroom for example) and this depletes the available space, but more importantly the remaining HD space on the boot volumes (especially nowadays with Apple's soldered SSDs) the remaining pace is not enough for the scratch disk and it fails. I experience it a lot with Lightroom doing Panorama,s temp files can be hundred of Gigagbytes. Unfortunately, you can't set the scratch disk location, contrary to photoshop. It writes to the TMPDIR.

So I would like to move that TMPDIR to another external SSD. I tried the symbolic link but unfortunately, I don't have the permission to overwrite or rename the current temporary folder.

Maybe there's a way to change the way the TMPDIR is create so it does it on another drive than the boot drive, or maybe I could get the permission to modify the current one.

Thanks.

Given the fact that lots of program used that location that is often too small, it would be a major boon to get a method to put that TMPDIR on another drive.

I tried Export TMPDIR, but LR still uses the root volume one

Thanks

MacOS big sur, Latest Lightroom Classic 11.2

Comment: Nice edit - even if this isn’t possible in general, perhaps someone knows for your specific case. I have never been able to exhaust writes on Apple OEM drives, but perhaps someone has in less than three years.

Comment: I don't want to do this for SSD wearing out, but because it needs more space than available

Comment: How big is your system disk? and your RAM?  This https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic-discussions/lr-classic-changing-the-temp-scratch-drive-it-fills-up-my-start-up-drive-completely-with-some/m-p/9582307 (which has unhelpful posts from Windows users) suggests that this is an unresolved issue with LR on Mac.

Comment: Are you sure that LR is using TMPDIR? And if so, which folder in there?

Comment: My apologies - not sure how I got that from the description.

Comment: "I tried the symbolic link but unfortunately, I don't have the permission to overwrite or rename the current temporary folder." If you _really_ want to, you can give yourself permission to modify any file on macOS; that's (IMO) the nice thing about macOS as opposed to iOS. You need to turn off System Integrity Protection, and you may or may not need to modify the root snapshot—these are all easily googlable terms. I can't say for sure, but I really would expect a symlink to work once done.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you’ll have good luck mapping any sort of TMP as multiple idioms exist (unix and posix temp and `mktemp` are different locations than Library Application Support sandboxes and caches). Furthermore, privacy concerns change these paths regularly so that scripts that attempt to access temporary files need to check in multiple locations. Unless you have a very narrow range of programs to wrangle, the general solution might be to put these in containers or VM and have that storage where you desire.

1. Contact the vendor and ask if their software can be configured for dumping files on the external. This is almost always an intentional design, not that they read an env type variable, but that you explicitly add a “scratch disk” of your choosing. Apple does this with Sharing Preference pane - you can select an external disk for content caching. Photoshop used to do that with “scratch disk” election.
2. Move other large files to the external - good candidates are the media in your Music / iTunes library, video files for iMovie and Final Cut Pro, Photos database.
3. Move your whole user home folder to an external drive - these files almost always are far less sensitive to a slower storage than the fastest NVMExpress SSD storage.

With respect to item 1 - There is an optimize performance article that may help if you can choose

- https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/kb/optimize-performance-lightroom.html

> To further speed the cache, keep it on a fast hard disk. To specify the location of the Camera Raw cache, do the following:
>
> - Choose Lightroom > Preferences (Mac OS) or Edit > Preferences (Windows).
> - Click the File Handling tab.
> - In the Camera Raw Cache Settings area, click Choose and navigate to the location where you want to store the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I managed to do it, by disabling SIP and then create a symbolic link to another drive as a replacement of the TMPDIR folder.

Original TMPDIR was T :
/var/folders/jc/myw_64vd1vb2zsn9wps4_xnh0000gp/T

More exactly I created a symbolic to my other drive folder in the folder myw_64vd1vb2zsn9wps4_xnh0000gp and named it A.

Then I renamed the T Folder to G and then the symbolink link A to T. You've to be quick as the OS recreates T quickly.

Of course, Lightroom must be quit before doing that. But it works.

It works, but of course, you've to disable SIP which is a pain. Also, after that photoshop doesn't work anymore, other programs mays fail also.

Now, the real solution would be to tell mac os to create the temp folder to and external drive. But that's another topic. I feel it has to to with the mktemp command, If we could ask it to use and external drive it would be the perfect solution.

So the solution was to disable SIP, and then you can move the TMPDIR with a symbolic link.

Comment: I'm not sure that the path is constant. E.g. after reboot, the "myw_64vd1vb2zsn9wps4_xnh0000gp" portion may change.